# uploading files to blobstore whilst handling other fields

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have a form with a file input and a few text fields and i'd like to Upload the file to the blobstore and then handle the rest of the input. I have found documentation from google but I'm still fuzzy on the details. If I have the right idea you first generate a submit url for the form like so:

```
 blobstore.create_upload_url('/handlerURL')
```

where handlerURL is the url of the request handler that process the regular form data such as text fields etc

Next you define a `BlobstoreUploadHandler`, this is where i get fuzzy... From the documentation I understand that the `BlobstoreUploadHandler` deals with uploading the file then passes a rewritten request to `\handlerURL`. My confusion arrises when in the docs here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers

an instance of a data model object is created inside the `BlobstoreUploadHandler`

but if i were to want to do additional processing and use data from other fields in the request handler at `handlerURL` then the `BlobstoreUploadHandler` would just be empty, is this correct or am i misunderstanding the process?

Answer (score 2):

BlobstoreUploadHandler just sanitizes the file upload part of the multipart message, you can still access the rest of the fields of your form using [webapp](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms) the standard way (e.g. self.request.get('some_field_in_the _form')).

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a little tricky as two handlers are involved here.

- The first one is from blobstore itself. Its URL is returned by the
  create_upload_url call. It's task is to save file (or files), and to
  replace it with blobkey. Then it just posts the form to your main
  handler.
- The second one is defined by you. In your case its URL is
  /handlerURL. In most cases BlobstoreUploadHandler is used here, but
  it doesn't have to. BlobstoreUploadHandler makes it easier to
  retrieve blobkeys and that's all about it. Apart from that it's just
  a webapp.RequestHandler, so you can process your whole form here